# CoreUI React Re-Routing after login is not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, core-ui

So, I just fixed my app so that after there is success logging in, the home page should display. However, after this, the rest of my routing has seemed to magically disappear. Here is the relevant code:

DefaultLayout.js

```
class DefaultLayout extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       name:'',
       redirect: false,
   };
}

componentDidMount() {
     let data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('userData'));
     console.log(data);
}

  render() {
    if(!sessionStorage.getItem('userData') || this.state.redirect){
    return (<Redirect to={'/404'}/>)
}

    return (
      <div className="app">
        <AppHeader fixed>
          <DefaultHeader />
        </AppHeader>
        <div className="app-body">
          <AppSidebar fixed display="lg">
            <AppSidebarHeader />
            <AppSidebarForm />
            <AppSidebarNav navConfig={navigation} {...this.props} />
            <AppSidebarFooter />
            <AppSidebarMinimizer />
          </AppSidebar>
          <main className="main">
            <AppBreadcrumb appRoutes={routes}/>
            <Container fluid>
              <Switch>
                {routes.map((route, idx) => {
                    return route.component ? (<Route key={idx} path={route.path} exact={route.exact} name={route.name} render={props => (
                        <route.component {...props} />
                      )} />)
                      : (null);
                  },
                )}
                <Redirect from="/home" to="/dashboard" />
              </Switch>
            </Container>
          </main>
```

Login.js

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
       this.state = {
       loginError: false,
       redirect: false
};
this.signup = this.signup.bind(this);
}
signup(res, type) {
  let postData;
  if (type === 'google' && res.w3.U3) {
  postData = {
    email: res.profileObj.email,
    name: res.profileObj.name,
    googleId: res.profileObj.googleId,
    googleAccessToken: res.Zi.access_token,
    googleImageURL: res.profileObj.imageURL
  };
 }


if (postData) {
  PostData('v1/zuulusers', postData).then((result) => {
     let responseJson = result;
     sessionStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(responseJson));
     this.setState({redirect: true});
  });
  } else {}
}
render() {

  if (this.state.redirect || sessionStorage.getItem('userData')) {
    return (<Redirect to={'/home'}/>)
}
const responseGoogle = (response) => {
  console.log("google console");
  console.log(response);
  this.signup(response, 'google');
}

    return (


      <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">
        <Container>
          <Row className="justify-content-center">
            <Col md="5">
              <CardGroup>
                <Card className="text-white py-5 d-md-down-none" style={{ width: '44%' }}>
                  <CardBody className="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <h2>Login if you dare</h2>
                      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/whatif-assets-cdn/images/asset_1+copy2.png" alt="zuul logo" id="zuul_logo" className="mx-auto d-block rounded img-avatar"/>
                          <GoogleLogin
                            clientId="24656564867-3issjp4bq0gsr05banuomnniilngiicc.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                            buttonText="Login with Google"
                            onSuccess={responseGoogle}
                            onFailure={responseGoogle}
                          />
                    </div>
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route  path="/home" name="Home Page" component={DefaultLayout} />
          <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" component={Page404} />
          <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" component={Page500} />
          <Route exact path="/" name="login" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

And then this is a small section of code to show how the routing is set up in CoreUI:

routes.js

```
const LoadingButtons = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Buttons/LoadingButtons'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Charts = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Charts'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Dashboard = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Dashboard'),
  loading: Loading,
});
const routes = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Login', component: Login, exact: true },
  { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: DefaultLayout, exact: true},
  { path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: Dashboard },
```

For some reason, after the homepage loads, it doesn't load any of the other pages. They just come up blank but the path is defined in the URL. Not sure what I m doing wrong in routing.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than checking in DefaultLayout which is a container for all navs, try doing so inside , since you are redirecting the routes there.

```
<Switch>
 {routes.map((route, idx) => {
   return route.component ? (
     <Route
       key={idx}
       path={route.path}
       exact={route.exact}
       name={route.name}
       render={props =>
        sessionStorage.getItem('userData') !== null (
         <route.component {...props} />  ) : (
         <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} /> ) //your route here
       }
      />
     ) : null;
  })}
 <Redirect from="/" to="/dashboard" />
</Switch>
```

Here, all routes are checked for authentication. If logged in, then user can access it else redirect to login or 404 as your preference.

Answer (score 0):

@Asteriscus answer, worked to me after adding "?" in `sessionStorage.getItem('userData') !== null ?` and changing `<Redirect from="/" to="/dashboard" />` to  `<Redirect from="/" to="/login" />` to ensure only authenticated user accessing dashboard